# Can't login to docker with aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, docker

This is an extension of my last question considering I've decided to deploy a Docker container onto a ton of EC2's. I've set up a repository and a user with full rights, and I added the correct keys to my aws cli configuration. When I try to run the docker login command that comes up after running the "aws ecr get-login" command, it gives me a failed with status: 403 forbidden error. I have absolutely no clue what's going on, and I've spent the past 2 days trying to fix this error... Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Looks to me like a permissions thing. What security group is your EC2 instance in? What are the inbound/outbound rules?

Comment: I haven't even set up the EC2's yet. This is just getting the ECR repository set up with the Docker image I've created.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check the security group of the EC2 Instance

To allow access via SSH you have to apply the following settings for the Security Group of the EC2 Instance:

[Security Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kytg7.png)